# Zsh customized prompt and updating variable's value

Tags: zsh, prompt

I would like to use the value of a variable set in my zsh shell to display in my prompt line.

For example, let's say `export TOKEN='hello'` is set in my session. At that time, I load my prompt which contains a `"$TOKEN"`.

This works fine, and the prompt is correctly displayed. However, if I change the value of TOKEN, my prompt do not get updated.

How do I make zsh to update my prompt every time I have executed a command?

Comment: zsh runs on many other platforms aside from Linux, most importantly, Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you could do this. You should look into the `precmd` and `preexec` functions. They're in the `hook functions` section of `zshmisc` (which you can read [online](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/zshmisc/) or using `man zshmisc`.

A simple solution would be to read [this unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32124/set-variables-in-zsh-precmd-and-reference-them-in-the-prompt) question, which says to put this in your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
 setopt prompt_subst
 PROMPT='$TOKEN'
```

This will do what you want:

```
 ┌─(simont@charmander:s000)─────────────────────────────────────▸▸▸▸▸▸▸▸▸▸─(~  )─┐
 └─(12:44)── export GREETING="foo"                                 ──(Wed,Dec12)─┘
 foo ┌─(simont@charmander:s000)─────────────────────────────────▸▸▸▸▸▸▸▸▸▸─(~  )─┐
 └─(12:44)── export GREETING="bar"                                 ──(Wed,Dec12)─┘
 bar ┌─(simont@charmander:s000)─────────────────────────────────▸▸▸▸▸▸▸▸▸▸─(~  )─┐
 └─(12:44)──
```

(This messes up my prompt a little, but you can see the `foo` and `bar` displaying nicely as they should, updating when `$GREETING` is changed. In your case, use `$TOKEN`).

My prompt *heavily* borrows from [Phil!'s ZSH Prompt](http://aperiodic.net/phil/prompt/), which I found very useful when learning to customise mine.